# remove caption from sub-figures Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to use following code. however when i remove caption part form sub figure. i am unable to refer them in text. I do not want sub-figure captions to show in PDF generated by latex and also want to ref them as for example Fig 1A. when i remove caption part out put is like this Fig ?? it should be like Fig 1A etc.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of May}
  \label{fig:csmay}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of June}
  \label{fig:csjune}
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of July}
  \label{fig:csjuly}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of the \#NigeriaDecides}
  \label{fig:csds}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{{\bf Connection pattern for conversation starters}}
\label{fig:allresultscs}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I am calling figure with \ref{fig:csmay} and so on in latex

Comment: Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/ and add all information to your question. Comments are not suitable to provide more information. Include what packages you use. Create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I assume your `subfigure`s are already labelled with `A`, `B`, ... and that's why you don't want the `\caption`s to show anything, correct? Are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: Dear Warner
Sir i am using ref{} not hyperref.

Comment: Please provide a compilable example.

Comment: i have solved the issue.